# Would it be technically possible to convert a Android executable (.apk) to a Java executable? (.jar)

Tags: java, android, apk

Would it be technically possible to convert a Android executable to a Java executable? If so, how? I've seen questions like this before on here but they were for the classes to a .jar (which acted more like a zip file) so I found no use for it as it wasn't the actual apk. (which also can act like a zip file)

Comment: An APK is not an Android executable. But more importantly, what would you expect to happen when executing that jar?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer with explanation:

An Android apk can be decompiled to java class files with the [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) application. This way you can take a look at the classes and even try to decompile them to java source files. But an Android application links against (depends on) the android framework with its libraries and runtime environment. You can't just recompile those java files on a standard JDK since that lacks both the Android framework's libraries and its runtime.

Sadly there are misunderstandings on what "java" is. There are many things that make up "java" as a programming and runtime environment. Just to name a few: there is the byte code specification, the JVM specification, the java language specification and the java core libraries (java API) specifications.

But one can decide to take only a subset of these and build something on top of that. You could use the JVM and the byte code with any language as long as it compiled to valid class files. You may omit java core libraries and so on. (See Scala or Clojure)

And that is exactly what Android has done. It took parts of the Java APIs and byte code and built something on top of that but also added its own libraries that have nothing to do with Oracle's java spec. So even though you can extract some class files out of APKs, those are not class files that were meant to be run on a standard java runtime environment.